# Can I achieve multiple endings on one playthrough?

Tags: deaths-door

While playing  Death's Door I've come to realize that there are multiple endings. I'm not quite sure how many endings there are, but I know there's at least two, one of which is considered the "True Ending". I have no idea how to achieve this ending, and I'd like to avoid spoiling it for myself. However, I'm also not interested in doing a second playthrough once I finish my first one (at least not right away).

So, ideally, I'd like to just keep playing as I am, and once I beat the "final" boss, then I can worry about trying to achieve this "True" ending (if I haven't already). However, I'm not sure if that's possible, since many games will lock you out of the  "True" ending past a certain point, forcing you to do a second playthrough.

**Can I achieve multiple endings on one playthrough? Is there a "point of no return", past which, I'll be locked out of achieving the "True" Ending for that playthrough?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** You can only achieve the True Ending after you beat the final boss for the first time. Doing so will give you an item which allows you to start pursuing the True Ending. So there's no reason to worry about locking yourself out of any content. Just play the game normally, and once you beat the final boss, you'll be able to start going after the True Ending.